# Нужно расширить возможности визуального редактора wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужно добавить в визуальный редактор wordpress возможность выбора обертки для поста

```
<div class="big_content_item">CONTENT</div>
```

или

```
<div class="wide_content_item">CONTENT</div>
```

или

```
<div class="content_item">CONTENT</div>
```

И чтобы в визуальном редакторе был select с вариантами big, wide, content соответствующий каждой обертке.

Судя по всему нужно добавить какой-то хук. Но пока что не особо понимаю с чего начать. Может кто-нибудь наведет на мысль?

Answer (score 2):

Для модификации контента есть хук `the_content`. Чтобы не лезть в дебри написания плагинов для визуального редактора (из вопроса не ясно, кстати, что это за редактор - стандартный или Visual Editor или Page Builder и т.д.), можно инструктировать пользователя вносить в текст поста следующее:

```
[big_content] или [wide_content] или [content]
```

Тогда нижеприведенный фильтр контента уберет указанный пользователем текст в квадратных скобках и обернет контент в требуемые div-ы.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_content');
function filter_content( $content ){
    modify_content($content, '[big_content]', '<div class="big_content_item"';
    modify_content($content, '[wide_content]', '<div class="wide_content_item"');
    modify_content($content, '[content]', '<div class="content_item"');
    return $content;
}
function modify_content($content, $code, $wrap) {
    if (substr($content, $code) {
        $content = str_replace($code, '');
        return $wrap . $content . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Исправил ответ, код не полностью вначале записался.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь о добавлении в контент html-обёртки произвольного контента то вот мой старенький плагин из 2х файлов. Он добавляет в редактор кнопку по который вставляется html-код. (идея плагина - для добавления "отзывов" в контент. Потом стилями придаётся внешний вид ;))

файл `plugin.php`

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Вставка отзывов
Plugin URI: 
Description: Создаёт блоки текста . Добавляет кнопку в редактор для вставки кода. 
Version: 1.0
Author: SeVlad
Author URI: http://sevladwp.wordpress.com/
*/


//Добавление кнопки в редактор
function true_add_mce_button() {
    // проверяем права пользователя - может ли он редактировать посты и страницы
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        return; // если не может, то и кнопка ему не понадобится, в этом случае выходим из функции
    }
    // проверяем, включен ли визуальный редактор у пользователя в настройках (если нет, то и кнопку подключать незачем)
    if ( 'true' == get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'true_add_tinymce_script' );
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'true_register_mce_button' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'true_add_mce_button');

// В этом функции указываем ссылку на JavaScript-файл кнопки
function true_add_tinymce_script( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['ref_mce_button'] =  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'refbuttons.js'; // ref_mce_button - идентификатор кнопки
    return $plugin_array;
}

// Регистрируем кнопку в редакторе
function true_register_mce_button( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'ref_mce_button' ); // ref_mce_button - идентификатор кнопки
    return $buttons;
}
 ?>
```

Файл `refbuttons.js`. В нём весь цимес.

```js
(function() {
 tinymce.PluginManager.add('ref_mce_button', function( editor, url ) {
            editor.addButton( 'ref_mce_button', {
                title: 'Отзывы',
                icon: 'icon dashicons-before dashicons-carrot', 
                onclick: function() {
     editor.windowManager.open( {
     title: 'Отзывы по теме',
     body: [
      {
       type: 'textbox', // тип textbox = текстовое поле
       name: 'refbody', // ID, будет использоваться ниже
       label: 'Текст', // лейбл
       value: '', // значение по умолчанию
       multiline: true, // большое текстовое поле - textarea
       minWidth: 300, // минимальная ширина в пикселях
       minHeight: 100 // минимальная высота в пикселях
      },
      {
       type: 'textbox',
       name: 'refname', 
       label: 'Имя/ник автора', 
       value: ''
      },
      {
       type: 'textbox', 
       name: 'refsource',
       label: 'Источник',
       value: '' 
      }
     ],
     onsubmit: function( e ) { // это будет происходить после заполнения полей и нажатии кнопки отправки
     editor.insertContent( '<div class="external-reference"><div class="external-reference-body">' + e.data.refbody + '</div><div class="external-reference-name">' + e.data.refname + '</div><div class="external-reference-source">' + e.data.refsource + '</div></div><p>&nbsp;</p>');
         }
    });
  }
 });
     });
})();
```

Comment: Это OK, если у ТС tinymce, чего мы не знаем наверняка.

Comment: @KAGGDesign  Я думаю, если бы использовалось что-то другое, то это было бы указано. А раз нет - значит речь о родном.

Comment: Возможно, но я столько раз встречал заказчиков, которые и не представляли, что во вселенной существует нечто иное, чем Page Builder, например )))